# RegEx to remove new line feed at starting and ending in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, linefeed

My data contains lots of new line feeds at starting and end of string, which is making difficulty in understanding data. Sample data is shown as below.

> '
>
> sample text
>
> new value
>
> '

I tried to replace chr(10) with empty string, but it was removing line feed between two lines which is required.

My Code

```
select REPLACE(a1, chr(10), ' ') from( select  '

Sample Text

New value

' as a1 from dual);
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `TRIM`:

```
SELECT
    TRIM(CHR(10) FROM col)
FROM dual
```

`TRIM` has the option to specify a character to remove from the beginning and ending of the string.  Follow the short demo below to see it in action.  Click [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php) to see how to use `TRIM` with a number of examples.

**Edit:** If you have a CLOB column and `TRIM` won't work, then we can still use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^' || CHR(10) || '*', ''),
    CHR(10) || '*$', '') AS output
FROM dual
```

Here is a demo showing that `REGEXP_REPLACE` works in place of `TRIM`:

### Demo

Comment: @Ashwin I have a solution for CLOB.  Posting now.

Comment: Sure, Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Please post the solution for CLOB as well.

Comment: @Ashwin Reload your page :-)

Comment: After replacing html tags with empty string(using Regexp) its breaking into new line, like `<html>
<body>
<td>source string <b>bold<\b> with html tags<\td>
</body>
</html>`
Both the functions are not able to remove this new line breaks.

Comment: @Ashwin I don't understand your new problem, because I can't see the formatting in a comment.  If this is related to trimming `CHR(10)` from the beginning and end of the string, then update your question.  If not, then you should really open a new question.  SO is not a blog site.

Comment: Sure, I'll Post it as an another question.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to trim or remove the line feed/carriage returns/tab is using
"translate(column_name, chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(09), ' ') ".
This worked for me.